# Using an external file on a button in html

Tags: javascript, html, button

```
<button onclick = "button javascript.js">
What do you drive? </button>
```

I want the button to run my switch() in the button javascript.js file

```
var car = prompt('What car?');

switch(car) {
case 'ferrari':
   document.write("you are probs a baller then");
     break;
case "porsche":
   document.write("do you ball hard?");
     break;
case "dodge":
   document.write("american cannot corner");
     break;
default:
   document.write("your car better be a subaru");
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? And what doesn't work? That way we can guide you better. Also show the code for your javascript.js file.

Comment: @matrixanomaly  <script src = 'button javascript.js'> </script>  works when i run the file but I want it to run when i click the button on the html webpage.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the code in a function inside the javascript. Include the file in script tags and on click of the button, call that function. That will trigger the JS code only on click of the button.

Put this in the HTML,

```
<script src='button javascript.js'></script>
//Intermediate HTML code
<button onclick = "myButtonFun()">
What do you drive? </button>
```

And in the Javascript you can put in your code in the function `myButtonFun()`

```
function myButtonFun()
{
  var car = prompt('What car?');

  switch(car) {
  case 'ferrari': document.write("you are probs a baller then");
                  break;
  case "porsche": document.write("do you ball hard?");
                  break;
  case "dodge":   document.write("american cannot corner");
                  break;
  default:        document.write("your car better be a subaru");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your code into a function and, on the button, use

```
type="button"
```

and

```
onclick="yourFunction()"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your script into function and invoke it on button click:

```
<button onclick = "askForCar();">What do you drive?</button>

var askForCar = function() {
  //you script here
};
```

```js
var askCar = function() {
  switch (prompt('What car?')) {
    case 'ferrari':
      document.write("you are probs a baller then");
      break;
    case "porsche":
      document.write("do you ball hard?");
      break;
    case "dodge":
      document.write("american cannot corner");
      break;
    default:
      document.write("your car better be a subaru");
  }
};
```

```html
<button onclick="askCar();">What do you drive?</button>
```